# Toddlers friendly flash cards

Tags: flashcards

How can I make the following.[image]

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[avery5371,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Segoe Print}


\cardfrontstyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textcolor{blue}{ \huge \bf Days of the week }
\end{center}

\cardfrontfoot{}
\begin{flashcard}{\textcolor{green}{\Huge MONDAY}}
%\Large \ce{SO4^2- + Ba^2+ -> BaSO4 v}
\end{flashcard}

\cardfrontfoot{Humor}
\begin{flashcard}[Acronyms]{ASAP}
 {\large Act swiftly awesome pachyderm.} \\  
(Dr Seuss' story \emph{Horton Hears a Who})

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{HortonHearsAWhoBookCover.jpg}
\end{flashcard}

% source image on 
% http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b8/HortonHearsAWhoBookCover.jpg 

\begin{flashcard}[Question]{How many types of people understand binary code?}
There are 10 types: \\[2ex]Those who understand binary, \\and those who don't.
\end{flashcard}

\cardfrontfoot{\LaTeX{}}
\begin{flashcard}[Question]{How to make flashcards?\\[1ex]

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Puzzled}}
\Large Type \texttt{texdoc flashcards} \color{red}  !!!
\end{flashcard}

% SVG image converted to PDF with inkscape, source on 
% http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Puzzld.svg

\end{document}
```